# Can't install Websphere mq client error 1603

Tags: client, ibm-mq, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install a IBM WebSphere MQ Client v8.0.0.3 on a Windows 7 SP 1 Enterprise machine, however I fail.

The installation starts, I select the language, splash comes on and after a bit the splash goes away and I'm left with a "Installation Wizard was interrupted", even though I click nothing.

I run it as administrator, and am a member of the local administrators group.

The installation log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1ff7efe58fe7c006297

## Edit:

A colleague with the appropriate mqm rights tried to install it, but failed also.
Everyone else here uses Windows server 2008 SP1 enterprise and have no problem with the installation.

## Edit2:

It seems that the error is coming because of our directory structure:
 Error 1327.Invalid Drive: H:\
We have our local settings, including appsettings on a server, instead of on the local machine, and the installer doesn't like it. JDK gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have the full contents of the Client installer unpacked, in the same structure as in the zip? I'd check the license directory in particular.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for a Windows MQ install to fail.  In a Windows environment one of the frequent reasons is that even though the ID performing the install is an administrator, it doesn't have the correct domain rights.  These include, for example, to query the SAM on the Domain Controller.

Please see [Configure IBM MQ accounts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008820_.htm?lang=en) for instructions on how to configure the service account under which MQ will run.  Obviously, the account performing the install must have a superset of the same rights.  Since the question fails to mention this critical pre-req step, I'm assuming it hasn't been performed.

It is possible that prior installations or a failed install will leave artifacts on the server which interfere with subsequent installations.  This is especially true when installing V8.0.  Since there is at least one failed install in this case, I would recommend using the IBM provided cleanup tool as described in [Spring Cleaning a Windows MQ Installation](https://t-rob.net/2015/06/11/spring-cleaning-a-windows-mq-installation/).  This will remove old registry entries and directories that alter the behavior of the installer.

Branching out a bit further, the `1603` error from MSIEXEC is pretty generic.  According to the good folks at MSIGEEK, the following are some common causes for that error:

- Short file name creation is disabled on the target machine.
- An Install Script custom action is prototyped incorrectly.
- A file is locked and cannot be overwritten.
- The Microsoft Windows Installer Service is not installed correctly.
- The Windows Temp folders are full.

The full article on debugging 1603 errors [is here](http://www.msigeek.com/715/how-to-troubleshoot-the-error-1603-fatal-error-during-installation).

In this specific case, it appears one or more WMQ product prerequisites is not installed:

```
MSI (c) (5C:B4) [15:31:48:820]: Doing action: iwiListProductPrereqs
Action 15:31:48: iwiListProductPrereqs. Listing the product prerequisites
Action start 15:31:48: iwiListProductPrereqs.
MSI (c) (5C:84) [15:31:48:826]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ga2svit\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI7642.tmp, Entrypoint: iwiListProductPrereqs
1: 15:31:48 MQCA (CaProlog)(CaProlog) info: amqiwicn.dll Built on Jun 15 2015 at 23:18:37; version 8.0.0.3, build p800-003-150615.2 
1: 15:31:48 MQCA (CaProlog)(CaProlog) info: Property 'ProductName' value 'IBM WebSphere MQ' from property table 
1: 15:31:48 MQCA (CaProlog)(CaProlog) info: Property 'AMQEXTCA60000' not defined in property table 
1: 15:31:48 MQCA (CaProlog)(WhatMode) info: User name is 'ga2svit' 
1: 15:31:48 MQCA (CaProlog)(WhatMode) info: MSIRUNMODE_ROLLBACKENABLED 
1: 15:31:48 MQCA iwiListProductPrereqs(iwiListProductPrereqs) info: Property 'VersionNT' value '601' from property table 
CustomAction iwiListProductPrereqs returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 15:31:48: iwiListProductPrereqs. Return value 3.
```

Comment: There was only one prerequisite bundled with the package - axis, and that is to be installed afterwards into the installation directory.

Tried putting it into the default path, but no change.
Could it be the AMQEXTCA60000?

I just went to the IBM site and it doesn't list any prerequisites...
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1350550241693&osPlatform=Windows

Comment: "Prereq" from an IBM perspective and from the msiexec perspective are different things. The msiexec prereqs are often the successful completion of prior steps in the install.  Those might be from one of the common causes listed. Did you go to the linked article and try the diagnostics specified? Did you try the MQ cleanup from theo ther linked article?  Did you try to install the stand-alone IBM product not using MSI?

Comment: Yes, I tried all, not sure about the last one though. I used the setup.exe, however I think that ultimately also invokes the *.msi

Answer (score 0):

Everything T-Rob has said is valid and correct, however for this specific case, this feels like one you need to take up with IBM as a defect.

I've been looking through the source of the place you are failing and there is no valid codepath I can see from the last line you have traced before a subsequent line which would say something like "MMC prereq satisfied" (or not satisfied, or querying a property, but it would say *something*). This implies to me we have hit an unhandled exception in the code and hence aborted straight out.  You could try a silent install to see if that helps, but I wouldnt hold out much hope.

So for me the thing it seems to be trying to do is to look in the system directory for mmc.exe - Does that exist on your system and if so look at its properties and what is the version of that file (right mouse in explorer, properties and find the one listing the file properties)

Comment: mmc.exe is the Microsoft management console, I've used a few snapins and they work properly.
There is no version of it though (ships with every windows installation).
I'll try the silent install, but I'm afraid that will have no effect as you say.

Comment: I tried the silent install: msiexec /i "IBM WebSphere MQ.msi" /l*v c:\installwebsphere.log /q TRANSFORMS=":InstanceId2.mst;1033.mst" AGREETOLICENCSE="yes" REMOVEFEATURES="yes"

 Unsuccessful yet again though. Log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ec89661a3352d96b97c9
(For some reason I can't edit the previous comment)

Comment: Your silent install is failing as "1: 19:24:20 MQCA iwiInstallInitPri(iwiInstallInitPri) info: ***AGREETOLICENSE value '' not acceptable"... You have a typo on the command line for the parameter name (remove the 2nd 'C')

Comment: Corrected that, its now throwing:

MSI (s) (74:00) [11:35:42:179]: Product: IBM WebSphere MQ (Installation1) -- Error 1327.Invalid Drive: H:\

Which is the same error I get when installing java JDK, so I'd assume its something to do with the local policies.

Comment: Want to post the log somewhere and I'll take a quick look?

Comment: So on my system, a properties of c:\windows\system32\mmc.exe shows on the details tab that there is a version of 6.1.7600.16385 - does yours show the same?

Comment: The log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/638c6efcecf70e863f43

And I've got exactly the same version of mmc

Comment: I think you have 2 problems overall. The first reported one is definitely odd in terms of where it goes wrong and feels like an exception. This second feels like a windows msi issue unrelated to MQ per-se and whilst its probably fixable its not really what was reported... What is your H drive - is it a mounted network drive by any chance? It *feels* like H is valid in the user context but not once you switch to the msi server context.  (Is your command prompt already elevated when you issue the msiexec command?)

Comment: The H drive is on our servers and has all the user settings, such as appdata. I'll ask the infrastructure guys if its possible to move the app settings to a local setting and hopefully that would fix the issue. 
As stated in some other comment, the same error (H being invalid) also occurs when I try to install java JDK.

Answer (score 0):

We saw this problem with the V8 MQ installer.  I had Offline Files disabled on my Windows 7 box, and a coworker did not.  He disabled Offline Files, rebooted, and the installer succeeded.

Comment: To clarify, the error we saw was: Error 1327.Invalid Drive: H:\

Comment: And H: is what we use internally as our "home" directory, so that's probably where that came from.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this error and upon further investigation I realized that (using the `MQParms_silent.ini` file) I had forgotten to un-comment the `AGREETOLICENSE="yes"` from the provided default.
Hope that helps.